# NSURLSessionDataTask, Google Compute Engine and OAuth 2.0

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-compute-engine, nsurlsession

First off, I want to mention I'm a newbie in regards to Networking with iOS and using OAuth.

Anyway, what my end goal is to post a file to my Google Compute instance and receive a response using OAuth 2.0. (Edited) Sends a file to the instance, a php file is executed which then returns another file.

I have been able to "remove" the firewall in the sense that all http requests are valid; however, I no longer want it to be public.

My iOS client logs in with his/her google account, gets token and refresh token, then authorizes request.  I'm going to be honest, this is where I don't think I'm doing something properly.  I end up making another request with the already authorized request.

Where do I go from here? It will be greatly appreciated if you give some advice/point me in the right direction.  Thank you.

## Code Below

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIBarButtonItem *sendMsg = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(sendAndReceive)];

    UIBarButtonItem *undoMsg = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo target:self action:@selector(undoText)];
    
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:sendMsg];

    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:undoMsg];

    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"iOS to GCE"];

    [self displayGoogleSignInForScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute"];

}


#pragma mark - Google OAuth 2



-(void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
             error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSString *failedMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"Google Compute OAuth 2.0 - Failed!", [AppModel returnXMark]];
        NSLog(@"%@", failedMsg);
    
    } else {
        NSString *succeededMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"Google Compute OAuth 2.0 - Succeeded!", [AppModel returnCheckMark]];
        NSLog(@"%@\nOAuth2 Code:%@", succeededMsg, auth);
        
        self.auth = auth;
    }
}



-(void)displayGoogleSignInForScope:(NSString *)scope{

    NSString *clientID = [AppModel returnClientID];

    NSString *clientSecret = [AppModel returnClientSecret];
    
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;

    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope clientID:clientID clientSecret:clientSecret
                                                         keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName delegate:self
                                                         finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
    
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}




#pragma mark - PUTting and GETting With OAuth2



- (void)authentication:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth request:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request finishedWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSString *failedMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"Google Compute OAuth 2.0 - Request Auth - Failed!", [AppModel returnXMark]];
        NSLog(@"%@\nError Message: %@", failedMsg, error);
    } else {
        NSString *succeededMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"Google Compute OAuth 2.0 - Request Auth - Succeeded!", [AppModel returnCheckMark]];
        NSLog(@"%@", succeededMsg);
        
        NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            if([data length] != 0){
                NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self dataResponseAlert:strData];
                });
            }
        }];
        
        [uploadTask resume];
    }
}


-(BOOL)sendingMsg:(NSString *)theMsg toNSURL:(NSURL *)putNSURL withFileName:(NSString *)filename{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:putNSURL];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"uploadedMsg.txt"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[theMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    
    [self.auth authorizeRequest:request delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(authentication:request:finishedWithError:)];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",putNSURL);
    
    /*NSURLSessionDataTask *uploadTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if([data length] != 0){
            NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self dataResponseAlert:strData];
            });
        }
    }];
    
    [uploadTask resume];*/
    
    return YES;
}


-(void)sendAndReceive{
    NSURL *putNSURL = [AppModel returnPutURL];
    
    if(![self sendingMsg:[self.msgTextField text] toNSURL:putNSURL withFileName:@""])
        return;
}
```

Comment: Note that I have imported "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h" from the Google Toolbox for Mac

Comment: Or am I just supposed to set up OAuth in my php file and have GCE be public?

Answer (score 0):

As a whole, I have realized that I wasn't correctly looking at the issue.

After receiving the access token, I understand that I'm supposed to handle it from my own server side code while maintaining my GCE instance public.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/Jw7nAzViino